# Replace string with html tags in Smarty template

Tags: security, replace, smarty, xss

I want to replace search query with html tag in Smarty template but I have a problem.

When I use html tags in Smarty `replace()` function I get an error

This is my code for replace search query with html tag

```
{$tools[x].tool_title|replace:$q:'<b>$q</b>'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double quotes (to use variable value - otherwise it will be treated as raw string) and you need to use `nofilter`

For the following code:

```
{assign var="q" value="sample"}
{assign var="text" value="This is sample text"}
{$text|replace:$q:"<b>$q</b>" nofilter}
```

Output in page source is:

```
This is <b>sample</b> text
```

However you need to know it could be potentially danger. Consider the following code:

```
{assign var="q" value="sample"}
{assign var="text" value="This is sample text <script>alert('hello');</script>"}
{$text|replace:$q:"<b>$q</b>" nofilter}
```

it will display JavaScript alert because page source is now:

```
This is <b>sample</b> text <script>alert('hello');</script>
```

However it seems you can do something with it using the following code:

```
{assign var="q" value="sample"}
{assign var="text" value="This <b>is</b> sample text <script>alert('hello');</script>"}
{$text|escape|replace:$q:"<b>$q</b>" nofilter}
```

Page source for that will be:

```
This &lt;b&gt;is&lt;/b&gt; <b>sample</b> text &lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;hello&#039;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

Because you first use `escape` modifier to escape everything in `$text` variable and then on safe input you perform replace.